# How to use multi properties in class that contain one variable?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, enums

I have class named "config" that have private string variable named "param".

I need to get from "config" class "param" variable sometimes as int type sometimes as bool type or string.

As I understand I need create 3 properties in config class,each property have to convert type, as follow:

The first property converts string to int, the second converts string to bool, the third property gets me the string value.

The class should look something like this:

```
class Config
{
    private string param; 

   public int ParamAsInt
  {
    get 
    { 
        return int.Parse(param); 
    }
  }

  public bool ParamAsBool
  {
    get 
    { 
        return bool.Parse(param); 
    }
  }

  public string ParamAsString
  {
    get 
    { 
        return param; 
    }
  }

}
```

But I don't know how can those properties be used in accordance to the variable type that I want to get out of class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code won't compile - `int` and such are reserved keywords and cannot be used as identifiers. You can either try naming your properties something like `Int32Value`, `StringValue`, etc., or try this:

```
public static implicit operator bool (Config config)
{
    return bool.Parse(config.param);
}

public static implicit operator int (Config config)
{
    return int.Parse(config.param);
}
```

This will allow for much cleaner code:

```
Config c = GetConfig("foo");
var isFeatureEnabled = false || c;
var spacing = 23 + GetConfig("bar");
```

Comment: As for the issue stated above he would need more than one implicit conversions which i think C# doesn't support (*Evaluation of a user-defined conversion never involves more than one user-defined or lifted conversion operator.*)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to give your properties *names*.  How would you expect to reference them?  Something like this:

```
class Config
{
    private string param; 

    public int ParamAsInt
    {
        get 
        { 
            return int.Parse(param); 
        }
    }

    public bool ParamAsBool
    {
        get 
        { 
            return bool.Parse(param); 
        }
    }

    public string ParamAsString
    {
        get 
        { 
            return param; 
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I also fixed the casing in your calls to `.Parse()`.  C# is case-sensitive.  I also replaced the call to `bool.TryParse()` with `bool.Parse()`.  The former (when used correctly, which this wasn't because it was missing a parameter) will only tell you if it *is* a `bool`, it won't tell you what value the `bool` actually *has*.  (For example, `bool.TryParse('false' out someBool)` will return `true`.)

Of course, this code is a bit dangerous.  You'll want to start with some more defensive programming to check those values.  Basically, look up `TryParse()` and how to use it correctly.  Something like this, for example:

```
public int ParamAsInt
{
    get 
    { 
        var tmp = default(int);
        if (int.TryParse(param, out tmp))
            return tmp;
        else
            // do something else? throw a specific exception? 
    }
}
```

Additionally, what is the purpose of this code?  It seems like a very rushed and poor design.  For any given value of `param` (how is that even being *set*, by the way?) this just sort of randomly tries to expose typed properties for it.  If you guess the correct one, you're still left with others that will throw exceptions.  Surely there's a *much* cleaner way to accomplish what you're trying to do.  So what *are* you trying to do?